# I am at a loss moving from Spring XML to Java-config

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a `spring-secuiry.xml` and a `database.xml` that I need to move into the Java-config but I don't know how..

Here is my `sercuirty.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url access="hasRole('ROLE_VERIFIED_MEMBER')" pattern="/mrequest**" />
        <intercept-url pattern='/*' access='permitAll' />
        <form-login default-target-url="/visit" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="cpilling04@aol.com.dev" password="testing" authorities="ROLE_VERIFIED_MEMBER" />
            </user-service>

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

and here is my `database.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Last changed: $LastChangedDate: 2012-11-19 08:53:13 -0500 (Mon, 19 
        Nov 2012) $ @author $Author: johnathan.smith@uftwf.org $ @version $Revision: 
        829 $ -->

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.uftwf" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mySQLDB"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>org.uftwf.inquiry.model.MemberInquiryInformation</value>

            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">${format_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Can someone please show me how to change the following Java-config to have them:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.johnathanmsmith.mvc.web"})
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String MESSAGE_SOURCE = "/WEB-INF/classes/messages";

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebMVCConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public  ViewResolver resolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver url = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        url.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        url.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        url.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return url;
    }


    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource configureMessageSource() {
        logger.debug("setting up message source");
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename(MESSAGE_SOURCE);
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver lr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        lr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return lr;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        logger.debug("setting up resource handlers");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/").addResourceLocations("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        logger.debug("configureDefaultServletHandling");
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver simpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver b = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        mappings.put("org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound", "p404");
        mappings.put("org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException", "dataAccessFailure");
        mappings.put("org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException", "dataAccessFailure");
        b.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
        return b;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestTrackerConfig requestTrackerConfig()
    {
        RequestTrackerConfig tr = new RequestTrackerConfig();
        tr.setPassword("Waiting#$");
        tr.setUrl("https://uftwfrt01-dev.uftmasterad.org/REST/1.0");
        tr.setUser("root");

        return tr;
    }


}
```

Comment: A lot of code here, but not a lot of other information.  What is the problem you're having?  What is the Exception message?  What have you tried?  It's highly unlikely anyone will be able help you with just that giant wall of code.

Comment: Java Config Support is a planed feature for Spring Security 3.2.0 M2 https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1953

Comment: In the current state, Spring security configurations don't map very nicely to JavaConfig.  Your best bet might be to keep your security portions in xml config and import the xml in your JavaConfig.  You can always convert it over later with the next version of Spring Security as @Ralph suggests.

Comment: ok.. if I agree to keep the secuirty out how can I get the database stuff in... its

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has been pointed out in comments, Spring security isn't supported in the java config yet.

I converted a basic Spring mvc webapp to full (or as much as possible at the time) code configuration a little while ago.

You can check out [the whole project on github](https://github.com/robhinds/spring-code-configuration-webapp), that should all work out of the box, and also uses inializr/bootstrap stuff for web/html5 good practice too.

[My code config files are all here](https://github.com/robhinds/spring-code-configuration-webapp/tree/master/src/main/java/com/tmm/web/configuration)

As you can see for my security class, its kindof a cheat!

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

/**
 * Spring doesn't yet support pure java configuration of spring security
 * so this will just have to import the old fashioned xml file.
 * 
 * @author rob
 *
 */
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/security.xml")
public class SecurityConfiguration {}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since Spring-security 3.2 you have been able to convert Spring-security to Java based code config.  I have written it up on my blog here:  http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/spring-4-xml-to-annotation-configuration.html

(includes source code & full spring mvc project using Spring 4)

Answer (score 5):

### Let's do it - The database configuration without any XML i.e. everything annotation based.

I start off by creating a database crdential property file and intend to keep it in the application's classpath. I'll take an example with MySQL and Hibernate.

```
database.properties
-------------------
db.driver.class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname
db.username=myusername
db.password=mypassword
```

Now I'll create a Spring managed class to represent this configuration file.

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:database.properties"})
public class DatabaseConfiguration
{
    @Value("${db.driver.class}")
    private String mDriverClass;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String mConnectionURL;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String mUserID;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String mPassword;

    //Getters and setters for the above private variables.
}
```

Similarly I create a property file for defining hibernate specific properties. These properties too, I intent to keep in classpath.

```
hibernate.properties
--------------------
hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
hibernate.show_sql=false
```

Also the spring managed class defining this property file.

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:hibernate.properties"})
public class HibernateConfiguration
{
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String mHibernateDialect;

    @Value("${hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings}")
    private boolean mUseNewIdGeneratorMappings;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private boolean mHibernateShowSQL;

    //Setters and getters for above fields
}
```

Also a little property class (useful down the line) from using the above class HibernateConfiguration.

```
@Component
public class HibernateProperties
extends Properties
{
    @Autowired
    public HibernateProperties(HibernateConfiguration config)
    {
        setProperty("hibernate.dialect", config.getDialect());

        setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", config.useNewIdGeneratorMappings() ? "true" : "false");

        setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", config.showSQL() ? "true" : "false");
    }
}
```

Now I will go for a Spring managed configuration class (The one which replaces the application context xml file having database related configuration). Let me name it as DbAppConfig.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DbAppConfig
{

    @Autowired
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factory;

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public DataSource getDataSource(DatabaseConfiguration config)
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        datasource.setDriverClassName(config.getDriverClass());

        datasource.setUrl(config.getConnectionURL());

        datasource.setUsername(config.getUserID());

        datasource.setPassword(config.getPassword());

        return datasource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactoryBean(DataSource datasource, HibernateProperties properties)
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        factory.setDataSource(datasource);

        factory.setHibernateProperties(properties);

        factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"my.entity.packages.to.scan"});

        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * Since the LocalSessionFactoryBean is available on the context, the LocalSessionFactoryBean.getObject will supply
     * the session factory by the auto detection of spring.
     *
     * @param factory
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory factory)
    {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(factory);
    }

    /**
     * inclusion The PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer automatically lets the
     * annotation included property files to be scanned. setting it static to spawn on startup.
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() 
    {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ph = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

        ph.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);

        return ph;
    }
}
```

And that's it!
You have the spring managed transaction manager available. 
Just decorate the service (@Service steriotypes) classes with @Transactional and use your DAOs (@Repository stereotypes) in them.

Comment: How would you use this from a Spring MVC Controller?

Comment: autowire the service instance and use it.

Comment: Can I autowire the bean DataSource in my class SecurityConfig? I have a problem in same area from this topic which I explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749767/using-jdbcauthentication-in-spring-security-with-hibernate