# Using jdbcAuthentication in Spring Security with Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-security

I just finished an Spring application which is based on the `inMemoryAuthentication()`, and now, after verified all are working perfectly, I want use the JDBC Authentication.

I have three kinds of classes to handle the connection to the database:

1. `HibernateConfig`, based on the code presented in this blog post.
2. DAO and Entity class, one for each table from my database (in this current state, I have three: User, Role and User_Role)
3. And a UserService class, which implement `UserDetailsService`.

I read some articles on the Internet, and pratically all of them uses the following configuration for the class SecurityConfig:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
          .jdbcAuthentication()
              .dataSource(dataSource)
              .usersByUsernameQuery(getUserQuery())
              .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(getAuthoritiesQuery());
    }
```

What is an issue for me, since I don't have a Datasource class in my project. My current SecurityConfig is this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .usersByUsernameQuery(getUserQuery())
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(getAuthoritiesQuery());
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/image/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/spring/index").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/spring/login").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("senha")
                .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/spring/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/spring/index").permitAll();
    }

    private String getUserQuery() {
        return "SELECT login as username, senha as password "
                + "FROM usuario "
                + "WHERE login = ?";
    }

    private String getAuthoritiesQuery() {
        return "SELECT DISTINCT usuario.login as username, autorizacao.descricao as authority "
                + "FROM usuario, autorizacao_usuario, autorizacao "
                + "WHERE usuario.id = autorizacao_usuario.fk_usuario "
                + "AND autorizacao.id = autorizacao_usuario.fk_autorizacao "
                + "AND usuario.login = ? ";
    }

}
```

As you can see, I already made some adaptations for use JDBC Authentication, but I am still missing the part where I link this class to my Hibernate class.

Someone have any suggestions in how to make this?

**my HibernateConfig is this**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "org.webapp.persistence" })
public class HibernateConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
      sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.webapp.persistence.model" });
      sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

      return sessionFactory;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSource restDataSource() {
      BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassname"));
      dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
      dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
      dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

      return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   @Autowired
   public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
      HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
      txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

      return txManager;
   }

   @Bean
   public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
      return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
   }

   Properties hibernateProperties() {
      return new Properties() {
         /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
         }
      };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. All I needed to do was insert the following annotation in my class `SecurityConfig`:

```
@ComponentScan(value="org.webapp")
```

And now I can autowire my `DataSource` in this class

```
@Autowired
private DataSource restDataSource;

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(restDataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery(getUserQuery())
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(getAuthoritiesQuery());
}
```

Comment: can you please share what is your  request  url??